# Oracle, Is it possible to create multiple partitions on single table for different fields?

Tags: oracle, partition

About the oracle
Is it possible to create different partitions on one table using different fields?

For example, I have one table, and it has two Date columns, created_on and updated_on, which are frequently used as search conditions.

Even though I added an index, the entire data is too much, so I want to divide the partition because there is a performance problem, but I know that I can only write to one column.

`PARTITION BY RANGE(created_on)`

In this case, is there any possibility of performance degradation when selecting with updated_on?

Or is there a way to create a separate partition for updated_on as well?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can partition on multiple columns `PARTITION BY RANGE(created_on, updated_on)...`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Two dates could result in a lot of partitions and this isn't a pattern I've ever seen anybody use. A more important question is, how do you anticipate querying this table on `updated_on`? Can you give us a sample query you are trying to improve? And can you give more information on why the index didn't work for you?

Comment: What is the cardinality on these columns? When you have only few distinct values then an index is not so efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Is 'created_on' always going to be earlier than 'updated_on'? If we can assume that, I suggest partitioning your table based on 'created_on' and filtering on both 'created_on' and 'updated_on' rather than solely on 'updated_on' to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the automatic list partitioning feature available with 12.2 ++.
Multiple columns can be defined as partition keys.
The DB will automatically create a new partition for each combination of partition keys.
Much more handy than subpartitioning in the past.
But you should be aware of the max. number of combinations to keep the number of partitions in an acceptable range.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in Oracle, it is possible to create different partitions on one table using different fields. This can help improve performance when querying or manipulating the data based on specific criteria.

In your scenario, where you have two date columns, created_on and updated_on, you can create separate partitions based on each of these columns. This allows you to effectively manage your data and optimize queries using these date fields.

To achieve this, you can use a composite partitioning method. First, you can partition the table based on the created_on column using the PARTITION BY RANGE clause. This will divide the data into partitions based on the range of values in the created_on column. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  -- columns definition
)
PARTITION BY RANGE(created_on) (
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2024-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
  -- additional partitions as needed
);
```

Next, you can create subpartitions within each partition based on the updated_on column. This further divides the data within each partition based on the range of updated_on values. For example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table
  MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (created_on)
  SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (updated_on)
  SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
    SUBPARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    SUBPARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2024-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
    -- additional subpartitions as needed
  );
```

By using this approach, you can have separate partitions based on different columns, allowing you to efficiently query and manipulate the data based on either the created_on or updated_on criteria. It helps in avoiding performance degradation when selecting with the updated_on column.

Remember to carefully consider your data distribution and partitioning strategy based on your specific requirements and workload patterns. It's also recommended to consult Oracle's documentation and seek the guidance of database specialists for optimal table partitioning techniques in your specific environment.